# Cannot login using Swing

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I created a login GUI login form and tried to login if the username and password matches with that entered in the database. But, I am unable to login

I could not find any error in the code.

```
public class Login {
private JTextField nameTextField;
private JButton submitButton;
private JTextField passwordTextField;
private JLabel Message;
private JPanel LoginPanel;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Login");
    frame.setContentPane(new Login().LoginPanel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(650,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public Login() {
    submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Connection con = null;

            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java_db", "root", "");
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from employee");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    if (rs.getString("name").equals(nameTextField.getText()) && rs.getString("password").equals(passwordTextField.getText())) {
                        Message.setText("Login Success");
                    }
                    else {
                        Message.setText("Failed");
                    }
                }
                con.close();

            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    });
}}
```

If the password and username matches, I want the application to show the message "Login Success"

Comment: You set the text in the `Message` for every user encountered in the DB. So if the last one doesn't match, you get a login error

Comment: 1) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: This is really not how you should verify passwords. Please read up on how to securely hash and check passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're scanning the whole table and in fact check the username/password of the last element in the DB.
I would simply get the (unique) element corresponding to the username entered and verify the password.
Something like this:

```
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT password FROM employee WHERE name = ?");
st.setString(1, nameTextField.getText().trim());
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
if (rs.next() && rs.getString(1).equals(passwordTextField.getText()))
  Message.setText("Login Success");
else
  Message.setText("Failed");
rs.close();
con.close();
```